# Query HealthKit for list of existing WRITE permissions?

Tags: ios, healthkit

I understanding from the WWDC video that the HealthKit API does not allow apps to query what measures they are allowed to read, but I was under the impression the Health Kit API does allow users to query Health Kit for what kinds of data they are allowed to write. However I have not been able to find the command to do this. Where is this info listed in the docs? Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine your app's authorization status by calling `authorizationStatusForType:` on an `HKHealthStore` instance.  See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKHealthStore_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/HKHealthStore/authorizationStatusForType:)

Comment: so I have to query each type individually rather than querying for an array of all write permissions?

Comment: Yes, each type individually.